# How should i validate my JSON response using jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

my json response is as following:

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have to make rest api call and response will be json with follwing pattern

```
{
"glossary":{
  "title":{},
  "glossaryDiv" :{} 

 }
}
```

How should i validate my response containing above patter?

Comment: Add JSON Extractor with JSON Path expression as $.glossary

Comment: using json path extractor how to compare the whole json file? in case on multiple root

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion). Given you choose `groovy` in the "Language" dropdown you will get [Groovy built-in capabilities to parse JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) in order to check presence of the required fields.

Example solution would be something like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
if (json.glossary == null) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('glossary object was not found')
    return
}
if (json.glossary.title == null) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('glossary title object was not found')
    return
}

if (json.glossary.GlossDiv == null) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('glossary div object was not found')
    return
}
```

See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

---

Alternatively you can use [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project for the same, however in this case there will be much less capabilities.

Comment: (prev.getResponseData()) what will be this value?

Comment: `prev` is a shorthand for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), the code line basically retrieves parent sampler response data. The second error means that you are trying to parse an incorrect JSON